# Swift: hook into lifecycle functions of UIViewController via protocol with default implementation

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, hook

Is it somehow possible to have a protocol with a default implementation via protocol extension to get some code automatically executed by just implementing the protocol in various places?

Heres an example of what I mean:

```
protocol Greetable {
    func greet()
}

extension Greetable where Self: UIViewController {
  func greet() {
    print("Hello ViewController")
  }
  func viewDidLoadMagicFunctionHookIdontKnowIfItIsPossible() {
    greet()
  }
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController, Greetable {}
```

So I want to define a protocol, give it default implementations and then hook the extension to let's say viewDidLoad() or other functions without explicitly calling the greet function by myself in every instance.

Subclassing is not possible since I want to use UITableViewController, UIViewController, UINavigationController, UISplitViewController, etc. and I cannot create one generic baseclass for all of them at once.

I also don't want to go through all of my view controllers and call greet() in viewDidLoad() because what if I decide to move the greet() to viewDidAppear? I had to go through all the controllers and move the code.

By the way, the order of when this magic function would be called would not matter at all for me, in case I have two protocols with this magic.

I'm surely not the only one who thought about something like this and there are programmers a thousand times smarter than me who surely can exactly explain why and how or why it is not possible in Swift to "hook" yourself into a certain function call.